# the meaning of "in this accout“

Tags: meaning

*Ettinger portrayed the Arend–Heidegger relationship as a deeply pathological one that stretched from their first encounter in 1924 until Arendt's sudden death. **In this account** Heidegger was cast as the ruthless predator who bedded a naive vulnerable young student…*

Do you think that *in this account* means the phrase similar to *with respect/regard to* or *the account* just represents the text, Ettinger's book about Heidegger and Arend where Heideger plays the role of a villain?

Comment: Ettinger *portrayed* something. Some particular detail can be found in that *account, portrayal, description.* This usage isn't really connected to ***on** this account = for this reason, taking this into account*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sense here is your second conjecture: an *account* as a "telling", a narration of a story.

The metaphor which underlies this use of *account* seems to be something along the lines of "listing the events in their proper order". Interestingly, the same metaphor underlies the Germanic use of *tell* and its cognates, which originally meant "count, list" (compare Ger *zählen* = "count", *erzählen* = "narrate). Perhaps Old French started employing *conter*, from Latin *computare*, in words like *reconter* = "recount, narrate" sense under Frankish influence.